# There is no difference between using char[] and StringBuilder and string when concatenating strings

Tags: c#

It is said that `char[]` performs better that `StringBuilder` and `StringBuilder` performs better than `string` in terms of concatenation.

In my test there is no significant difference between using `StringBuilder` and `string` inside the loop. In fact the `char[]` is the slowest.

I am testing against the same table with 44 columns and 130,000 rows
the query is 
select * from test

Can someone help me see if I did something wrong?

The following is the code

```
//fetchByString(rd, fldCnt, delimiter, sw);            // duration: 3 seconds

//fetchByBuilder(rd, fldCnt, delimiter, sw, rsize);    // duration: 3 seconds

//fetchByCharArray(rd, fldCnt, delimiter, sw, rsize);  // duration: 7 seconds

private void fetchByString(OracleDataReader pReader, int pFldCnt, string pDelimiter, StreamWriter pWriter)
{
  while (pReader.Read())
  {
    string[] s = new string[pFldCnt];
    for (Int32 j = 0; j < pFldCnt; j++)
    {
      if (pReader.IsDBNull(j))
      {
        s[j] = "";
      }
      else
      {
        s[j] = pReader.GetValue(j).ToString();          // correct value
      }
    }
    pWriter.WriteLine(string.Join(pDelimiter, s));      
  }
}
private void fetchByBuilder(OracleDataReader pReader, int pFldCnt, string pDelimiter, StreamWriter pWriter, int pRowSzie)
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(pRowSzie);
  while (pReader.Read())
  {
    for (Int32 j = 0; j < pFldCnt; j++)
    {
      if (pReader.IsDBNull(j))
      {
        //sb.Append("");
        sb.Append(pDelimiter);
      }
      else
      {
        sb.Append(pReader.GetValue(j).ToString());          // correct value
        sb.Append(pDelimiter);
      }
    }
    pWriter.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    sb.Clear();
  }
}
private void fetchByCharArray(OracleDataReader pReader, int pFldCnt, string pDelimiter, StreamWriter pWriter, int pRowSzie)
{
  char[] rowArray;
  int sofar; 
  while (pReader.Read())
  {
    rowArray = new char[pRowSzie];
    sofar = 0;
    for (Int32 j = 0; j < pFldCnt; j++)
    {
      if (pReader.IsDBNull(j))
      {
        pDelimiter.CopyTo(0, rowArray, sofar, pDelimiter.Length);
        sofar += pDelimiter.Length;
      }
      else
      {
        pReader.GetValue(j).ToString().CopyTo(0, rowArray, sofar, pReader.GetValue(j).ToString().Length);
        sofar += pReader.GetValue(j).ToString().Length;
        pDelimiter.CopyTo(0, rowArray, sofar, pDelimiter.Length);
        sofar += pDelimiter.Length;
      }
    }
    string a = new string(rowArray).TrimEnd('\0');
    pWriter.WriteLine(a);
  }
}
```

Comment: Post the code you are profiling with. Is this with or without compiler optimizations? Are you in Debug or Release? There's not enough information here.

Comment: How much time is spent in `OracleDataReader` methods?

Comment: You are not going to get any useful information from these tests. You have IO operations happening alongside the concatenation tests you are attempting to 'profile'.

Comment: Why would you convert back and forth between strings and arrays, thereby copying chars around over and over again, and then expect it to be faster?  You can have either the speed of char arrays or the convenience of strings; in order to get both, you'd need a library that does string ops directly on char arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

StringBuilder is preferred over string concat because string concat frequently has to allocate temporary intermediate copies of the data with each + operator, which chews up a lot of memory fast and requires copying data multiple times.  StringBuilder.Append() is internally optimized to avoid copying or allocating the subsegments multiple times. All the work happens at StringBuilder.ToString, when the final size of the output string is known and it can be allocated in one call.

Your test cases aren't using string concat. You allocate a bunch of string fragments into an array of string, and then you call String.Join. That's essentially what StringBuilder does internally. Even after you remove the overhead of data I/O that may be dominating the benchmark times, I would expect String.Join() and StringBuilder.ToString() to produce similar performance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your answer explains why the StringBuilder and string[] performs the same. I appreciate it.

Comment: I am still wondering why the char[] is not performing better than StringBuilder. 

my timing is like this

      begin = DateTime.Now;
      fetchByString(rd, fldCnt, delimiter, sw);
      end = DateTime.Now;
      TimeSpan diff = end - begin;
      Console.WriteLine("duration = {0}",diff.Seconds.ToString());

Comment: The timing includes the calls to the reader. I accessed the reader the same way in the three methods with the same amount of data. The timing on accessing reader without string/char[] assignment is around 500 milliseconds throughout the loops.
cHao's answer touch the char[] assignment but I don't know a way to directly get char[] out of OracleDataReader. Anyone? 
I time the whole method because I want to improve the performance with the fastest way of putting data into output variables.

Comment: Well, you're calling pReader.GetValue(j).ToString() twice in the char[] routine. Assign that to a temp var, then work with the temp var in multiple locations. If the pReader caches data, the cost of calling twice will be just whatever data conversion is required to allocated and convert the data to string. If the pReader does not cache, then the cost is that it doubles your I/O overhead.

Comment: I don't know anything about OracleDataReader. If it favors char[] as a data format internally, then figuring out how to get access to that could be a performance plus. Otherwise, chances are that string is the favored internal format for string data. See if you can find out how the data is encoded in the database. If it's already Unicode in the database, then you shouldn't have any codepage conversion costs. If it's stored in a codepage encoding, having your client code match that encoding could save you a costly conversion step in ToString().

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with this claim, but there seems to be WAY more conversions going on in the `char[]` the way you've written it.

`pReader.GetValue().ToString()`, besides putting the value in a format that's not what you're working in (`string` instead of `char[]`), is happening 3 times in the `char[]` assignment as opposed to just 1 in the others.  You should probably find some way to cast your 'true value' directly to a `char[]` to be valid.  Otherwise from a benchmarking perspective you could theoretically be pulling down performance by introducing slowness from something else.  I'm not asserting that's what's happening, but procedurally it's considered important.  Even if you can't do that, I think you still might realize a small performance boost if you put in `var stringRep = pReader.GetValue().ToString()` and used `stringRep` instead of the associated GetValue/ToString call.

Incidentally, I'm not sure how you're timing this, but if you're not using the [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class you might look into it, just to be sure your timing is appropriate as well.  It's basically made with this sort of benchmarking in mind.  This would also allow you to actually isolate what you're trying to benchmark (the concatenation operations) without getting all that mess from the oracle reader in there as well.

Comment: Hi, I followed your suggestion to reduced the call to the reader and it reduced timing from 7 seconds down to 3 seconds.